# Is it possible to set two different prefixes for different sets of commands? [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have tried to do it myself, but it doesn't seem to work. This was the only way I could think of.

```py
bot1 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
bot2 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

...

bot1.run('token')
bot2.run('token')
```

Edit:
Here is an example of the type of commands I want to do

```py
py = commands.Bot(command_prefix='py')
js = commands.Bot(command_prefix='js')

@py.command("if")
async def py_if(ctx):
  ctx.send("if <cond>:")

@js.command("if")
async def js_if(ctx):
  ctx.send("if (<cond>){  }")

py.run('token')
js.run('token')
```

The multiple prefixes would allow you to use a different prefix for specific languages, in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in discord.py documentation:

> The command prefix is what the message content must contain initially to have a command invoked. This prefix could either be a string to indicate what the prefix should be, or a callable that takes in the bot as its first parameter and discord.Message as its second parameter and returns the prefix. This is to facilitate “dynamic” command prefixes. This callable can be either a regular function or a coroutine.

Also, you can use a collection of prefix strings. For example:

```
import random

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=('!', '?'))


@bot.command(name='random')
async def my_random(ctx):
    await ctx.send(random.random())


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

[Visit documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix)

EDIT: From documentation link:

> The command prefix could also be an iterable of strings indicating that multiple checks for the prefix should be used and the first one to match will be the invocation prefix. You can get this prefix via Context.prefix. To avoid confusion empty iterables are not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

```
bot1.run('token')
bot2.run('token')
```

You can't do this. `bot1.run('token')` is a blocking call. `bot2.run('token')` will not be executed. Thus only `bot1` will come online.

---

As Roman said with `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=('!', '?'))` you can have multiple prefixes for the same command.

```
@py.command("if")
async def py_if(ctx):
  ctx.send("if <cond>:")

@js.command("if")
async def js_if(ctx):
  ctx.send("if (<cond>){  }")
```

If you want to tie a command to a specific prefix you have to do something like this

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=('!', '?'))

@bot.command("myCommand")
async def myCommand(ctx):
  if ctx.prefix == "!":
    await ctx.send("Command was invoked with ! prefix")

bot.run('token')
```

see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=prefix#discord.ext.commands.Context.prefix

or:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=('!', '?'))

def check_prefix(ctx):  
  return ctx.prefix == "!"    

@bot.command("myCommand")
@commands.check(check_prefix)
async def myCommand(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Command was invoked with ! prefix")

bot.run('token')
```